# app crashes in iOS simulator depending on whether Xcode is running simulator or not

Tags: ios, xcode

when i hit 'run' from Xcode use the app it crashes, but when I hit 'stop' on Xcode and click on the app and use it on iOS simulator it works fine. do you know why?

Comment: Did this happen every time?  What happens right after you got it running on the simulator and then go back to Xcode and run it again without make any modification to the source code?

Comment: Everytime there is a crash OS crash reporter writes it to crash log. Goto ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ folder and find your AppName_date_time_username-id.crash log and look for why it crashed. Or post that info here so that someone can help you understand why it crashed.

Comment: Thanks. I think it has to do with 'activate break points' actually.